# XSL node-set from variable. Select not finding path.

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, msxsl

Slowly going mad over this and have tried various solutions found here but nothing seems to be working so far.

I have some XSL as such:

```
<xsl:variable name="reserved">
    <xsl:value-of select="utils:getReservedCodes()"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

The value of which is determined by some JScript:

```
function getReservedCodes() {
    reservedCodes = reservedCodesList.join("");
    return reservedCodes;
}
```

If I output the value of `reserved` using

```
<xsl:value-of select="$reserved"/>
```

I get something like this:

```
<codey value="-STB"></codey><codey value="-SO"></codey>
```

I'm then attempting to use the contents of this variable as a node set:

```
<xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($reserved)/codey">
    <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This for-each loop doesn't output anything. I get the impression from other answers here that this could be a namespace issue so I've tried declaring the variable with `xmlns=""`, I've surrounded all the `codey` entries with `<Codes xmlns="">` and I've also tried using the JScript prefix in case it was that but I can't seem to get anything to work.

I have no default namespace in my stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"    
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:utils="urn:utils">
```

and in case it's of any use, my script header looks like this:

```
<msxsl:script implements-prefix="utils" language="javascript">
```

If anyone out there has any suggestions I would be eternally grateful.

Comment: I don't see how `<xsl:value-of select="$reserved"/>` could create any element nodes (like the `codey` elements) at all as `xsl:value-of` simply creates a text node. So consider to provide minimal but complete sample to allow us to understand and reproduce the problem. What is the JScript function returning, a plain JScript string? Which XSLT processor do you use exactly, the `msxsl` namespace you use is support by the various MSXML versions but as well by the .NET implementations XslCompiledTransform and XslTransform and some third party competitors like XmlPrime.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it helps anyone else landing here, I managed to get around my issue by applying the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075427/xslt-1-0-convert-delimited-string-to-node-set) question and having my JScript return a comma-delimited string.